# Can you combine named parameter with short-hand constructor parameter?

Tags: constructor, dart, optional-parameters, named-parameters

In dart:

Named parameters function like so-

```dart
String send(msg, {rate: 'First Class'}) {
  return '${msg} was sent via ${rate}';
}

// you can use named parameters if the argument is optional
send("I'm poor", rate:'4th class'); // == "I'm poor was sent via 4th class"
```

Short-hand constructor parameters function like so-

```dart
class Person {
  String name;

  // parameters prefixed by 'this.' will assign to
  // instance variables automatically
  Person(this.name);
}
```

**Is there any way to do something like the below?-**

```dart
class Person{
   String name;
   String age;

   Person({this.name = "defaultName", this.age = "defaultAge"});
}

//So that I could do something like:
var personAlpha = new Person(name: "Jordan");
```

Thanks,

Code samples borrowed from [dartlang synonyms](https://www.dartlang.org/docs/synonyms/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Update

Yes, the `=` is allowed in Dart 2 and is now preferred over the `:` to match optional positional parameters.

```
Person({this.name = "defaultName", this.age = "defaultAge"});
```

### Old Answer

You just have to use a colon instead of equals

```dart
class Person {
   String name;
   String age;

   Person({this.name: "defaultName", this.age: "defaultAge"});
}
```

I find this still confusing that optional parameters use `=` to assign defaults but named use `:`.
Should ask myself.

Comment: The argument for this syntax was that it "looked like" Map literal syntax.

Comment: Now `=` is apparently allowed (preferred?) in place of the colon.

Comment: @Suragch thanks! Yes `=` was added for Dart 2 and it's now preferre to `:` to match optional positional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "this." syntax with all argument types. 
As answered above, you need ':' for default values for named parameters.

You can even use "this." for function typed parameters:

```dart
class C {
  Function bar;
  C({int this.bar(int x) : foo});

  static foo(int x) => x + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome too. Thanks Irn! How could bar be optional though? Both bar and foo have the required parameter of x; so, if you just didn't include bar as a parameter, then how would foo know what x is?

Comment: In this case, "bar" is just a standard optional parameter that expects a value. That value must have the function type (int->int), but it is otherwise no different from writing `C({String this.bar: 'bif'})`. If the argument is omitted, it will use the default value, otherwise it will use whatever argument is passed. You can call it as  `new C(bar:null)` or `new C(bar: (z) => -z)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add an required field to skip the default initialization, like so:

```dart
class ProcessArguments {
  final String logoImagePath;
  final String textLogoImagePath;

  ProcessArguments({required this.logoImagePath, required this.textLogoImagePath});
}
```